# Azure file storage: High count of ClientOtherError

Tags: azure, storage, fileshare

Just noticed that my fileshare storage in Azure has a very high rate of the "ClientOtherError" appearing. They're running at anywhere from 50-100% of the success count.

Anyone have any experience as to why this might be?

The attached graph shows the ClientOtherError transactions in red/orange and the successful transactions in blue.

[image]

Comment: Please take a look at the description for ClientOtherError here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-logged-operations-and-status-messages. Are you invoking a lot of "CreateIfNotExists" methods from the SDK? That could possibly explain the high occurrence of this error.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @GauravMantri, but I'm not using an SDK. I'm moving files from a local folder to the azure share using windows file explorer.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve the issue ?

Comment: No, I've found no solution. It does seem to vary from day to day. Some days the error rate is very high and some days it's somewhat lower.

Comment: @ChrisCarman Have you solved the problem? I got high file transactions in the storage account and couldn't find any solution

Comment: No solution, sorry. Hadn't looked at this in a long time before today, so I can't comment for a sufficient time period, but the last 24 hours have been perhaps slightly better, with errors running at a mere 25-50% of total transactions.

Comment: Hi Chris, did you found out what was going on with it?! i have the same issue and i don't know where those errors are comming from

Comment: No, still no resolution. TBH, I've mostly stopped looking at it, since it doesn't seem to be adding anything to the cost.

Answer (score 1):

[ClientOtherError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-logged-operations-and-status-messages) :

> Authorized request that failed as expected. This error can represent
> many 300-400 level HTTP status codes and conditions such as NotFound
> and ResourceAlreadyExists.

We came across very high percentage of **ClientOtherError** (Failed transaction by response type) with our Azure blob storage. However, in our case this error can be ignored. This was happening because operations were being performed on files that didn't exist. They were basically successful API calls that return non 200 HTTP status code. In our scenario, Failed transaction by API name showed below items.

- DeleteFile
- GetBlobProperties
- GetFileProperties

**blob storage example 1:**
[image]

**blob storage example 2:**
[image]

ClientOtherError usually means expected errors, such as not found and resource already exists. If your code uses APIs such as Exists, Create***IfNotExist(for example, CreateTableIfNotExist), those errors will be encountered frequently. Some examples of operations that execute successfully but that can result in unsuccessful HTTP status codes include:

- ResourceNotFound (Not Found 404), for example from a GET request to a blob that does not exist.
- ResourceAlreadyExists (Conflict 409), for example from a CreateIfNotExist operation where the resource already exists.
- ConditionNotMet (Not Modified 304), for example from a conditional operation such as when a client sends an ETag value and an HTTP If-None-Match header to request an image only if it has been updated since the last operation.

In order to debug this further, you can use [Azure storage logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging) which would log information about every operation performed against your storage account. It will include the HTTP code of every response.

Here is a [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/common-rest-api-error-codes) of common status codes. Many (not all) 300-400 level HTTP status code will result in ClientOtherError.

---

OP seems to face this problem with Azure file share. I suspect something similar is happening. The windows storage explorer application under the hood probably does similar API calls resulting in ClientOtherError.
File share here seems to have [similar API's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-logged-operations-and-status-messages#logged-operations) that can result in ClientOtherError when the file is missing.

I would say that in most of the cases this error is expected and can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

here my error rate as compare (Win FS and also used by AKS cluster)

I do a good amount of overwrites, maybe that contributes to the number of errors.

[image: Error to Success Rate]